# Firebase Xcode linker command error using Firebase Unity SDK

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Firebase Unity SDK 1.1.1.
Unity 5.5.0p4
XCode 8.2.1

When using Authentication and Database from Firebase I get the following error when building the project in XCode :

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRGoogleAuthProvider", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libAuth.a(credential_ios_ef8c3cf45c3329a5e5902f99026c639a.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRGitHubAuthProvider", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libAuth.a(credential_ios_ef8c3cf45c3329a5e5902f99026c639a.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIREmailPasswordAuthProvider", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libAuth.a(credential_ios_ef8c3cf45c3329a5e5902f99026c639a.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRFacebookAuthProvider", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libAuth.a(credential_ios_ef8c3cf45c3329a5e5902f99026c639a.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libApp.a(app_ios_c76c7d869e568a9b561ea55e25a7dcc0.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAuth", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libAuth.a(auth_ios_3c64a79cf1eb3f06f9309f4d8e91ee94.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRTwitterAuthProvider", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libAuth.a(credential_ios_ef8c3cf45c3329a5e5902f99026c639a.o)
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIROptions", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libApp.a(app_ios_c76c7d869e568a9b561ea55e25a7dcc0.o) ld: symbol(s) not
>   found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker command failed with
>   exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Do I miss something in XCode? Or have something to check in Unity?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the Firebase CocoaPod? If you are, are you opening a `.xcodeproj` file, or `.xcworkspace` file when you open the project?

Comment: I think I don't use CocoaPod. It just use 'build & run' from Unity. That generates an .xcode project, and open that project. And run the xcode project on my device.

Comment: I have the exact same link errors with Unity SDK 3.0.0 and Unity version Unity 5.5.0f3 (compiled from unity cloud build servers). This version is supposed to work with unity cloud build..older versions would generate pod errors much earlier in the build process

Answer (score 6):

I spent a couple of days trying to figure out the errors from building with Unity Cloud Build vs building locally. Hopefully this can help someone else!

### **Building Locally**

This just worked as long as you have CocoaPods installed. An error will appear in the Unity console after building for iOS if CocoaPods is not installed. Other than that, the instructions provided by Firebase worked fine with Unity 5.6 and Xcode 8.3.

### **Building with Unity Cloud Build**

CocoaPods is not available on UCB but Firebase has a non-CocoaPods alternative: https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks

**Add Frameworks Manually**

The instructions are assuming a native iOS build but you can simply drag the frameworks you need into Assets/Plugins/iOS/Firebase instead of into an Xcode project. Unity will add those frameworks to the Xcode project on build.

**Add Linker Flag**

You will need to manually add `-ObjC` into Other Link Flags. For some reason it showed up in my local Xcode project but not when UCB made the build. Create a post process script much like maros mentioned: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/problem-building-ios-app-with-cloud-build-using-google-analytics.390803/#post-2549911

You will need to add `-ObjC` like this:

`proj.AddBuildProperty(target, "OTHER_LDFLAGS", "-ObjC");`

If you do not add this part, UCB may still create a build but the game will crash immediately after trying to create FirebaseAuth as it will reference an extension/category method that was not included due to the missing `-ObjC` flag.

**Add Other Required Frameworks and Libraries**

Depending on which Firebase features you are using, you may need different additional frameworks or libs. For example I had used FirebaseDatabase and while the docs did not mention this, Xcode complained about a linker error that required me to add `libicucore.tbd`.

The best way I could think to solve this was uninstall CocoaPods locally and then have Unity create the Xcode project so that I could get a more accurate representation of what UCB would experience. This part may take some trial and error as well as Googling to figure out which framework or lib the linker error is referring to. Just try to build the Xcode project locally and you will get the linker errors if any.

I added:

```
List<string> frameworks = new List<string>() {
    "AdSupport.framework",
    "CoreData.framework",
    "SystemConfiguration.framework",
    "libz.dylib",
    "libsqlite3.dylib",
    "libicucore.tbd"
};
```

**Manually Move GoogleServices-Info.plist**

Another oddity is that UCB did not move the GoogleServices-Info.plist into the Xcode project. There must be some other script that is not running on UCB that does run locally. In the post process script where you add the linker flag and frameworks, you can also move the GoogleServices-Info.plist into the Xcode project directory and then add it to the bundle.

First move the file:

```
if (!File.Exists(path + "/GoogleService-Info.plist"))
{
    FileUtil.CopyFileOrDirectory ("GoogleService-Info.plist", path + "/GoogleService-Info.plist");
}
```

Then add it to the build:

```
string guid = proj.AddFile("GoogleService-Info.plist", "GoogleService-Info.plist");
proj.AddFileToBuild(target, guid);
```

And that should be it. I will update if I run into any other issues as I add more Firebase features. Currently I am using Auth, Database, and Analytics.

Answer (score 5):

First, thanks to all for sharing your (hard) work !

A lot has been said on the subject, but it took me a **lot** of time and a **lot** of trial and error to gather all the pieces on both SO & Unity forums, so I will just post the solution that I finally worked out, which finally solved all issues for me, using unity cloud build/Unity 5.6.0f3/Xcode 8.0, the project using only firebase analytics package

### SOLUTION FOR UNITY CLOUD BUILD

- completely disable cocoapods from Unity > Assets > Play Services Resolver > iOS Resolver > Settings (uncheck "Podfile Generation" and "Auto Install Cocoapod Tools in Editor", choose "None - do not integrate Cocoapods")
  p
- put GoogleServices-Info.plist in the Unity "Assets" folder
- PostBuildProcessor method:

---

```
private static void ProcessPostBuild (BuildTarget buildTarget, string path)
{
    // Only perform these steps for iOS builds
    #if UNITY_IOS

    Debug.Log ("[UNITY_IOS] ProcessPostBuild - Adding Google Analytics frameworks.");

    // Go get pbxproj file
    string projPath = path + "/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj";

    // PBXProject class represents a project build settings file,
    // here is how to read that in.
    PBXProject proj = new PBXProject ();
    proj.ReadFromFile (projPath);
    // This is the Xcode target in the generated project
    string target = proj.TargetGuidByName("Unity-iPhone");

    proj.AddBuildProperty(target, "OTHER_LDFLAGS", "-ObjC");
    proj.AddBuildProperty(target, "OTHER_LDFLAGS", "-v");
    proj.SetBuildProperty(target, "ENABLE_BITCODE", "NO");

    if (!File.Exists(path + "/GoogleService-Info.plist"))
    {
        FileUtil.CopyFileOrDirectory("Assets/GoogleService-Info.plist", path + "/GoogleService-Info.plist");
    }
    string guid = proj.AddFile("GoogleService-Info.plist", "GoogleService-Info.plist");
    proj.AddFileToBuild(target, guid);

    // List of frameworks that will be added to project
    List<string> frameworks = new List<string>() {
        "AddressBook.framework",
        "AdSupport.framework",
        "CoreData.framework",
        "SystemConfiguration.framework",
    };

    // Add each by name
    frameworks.ForEach((framework) => {
        proj.AddFrameworkToProject(target, framework, false);
    });

    // List of frameworks that will be added to project
    List<string> usrLibFrameworks = new List<string>() {
        "libsqlite3.tbd",
        "libz.tbd",
        "libicucore.tbd",
    };

    // Add each by name
    usrLibFrameworks.ForEach((framework) => {
        proj.AddFileToBuild(target, proj.AddFile("usr/lib/"+ framework, "Frameworks/" + framework, PBXSourceTree.Sdk));
    });


    // Write PBXProject object back to the file
    proj.WriteToFile (projPath);

    #endif
}
```

PS it's crazy that firebase unity sdk is requiring such hacks to work (UCB is an absolute requirement for us and I guess for most multiplatform mobile developers) and I hope all those workarounds will soon be useless, but judging that all those issues are here from the beginning of official firebase Unity support, I wouldn't count too much on it

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, just fixed it.

Find the Podfile file and open it in a text editor.
remove

> , :integrate_targets => false

in the second line so it says:
install! 'cocoapods'

Then add a new line after platform: ios...

> use_frameworks!

Then open a terminal screen and go to the directory of this project. Type 'pod install' and enter.
If everything goes well a workspace file is created and a message appears that you should open the workspace in Xcode in stead of the project. So close the project in xcode and open the projectname.xcworkspace file. Now Xcode will open the workspace and you will be able to run the project. You may have to adjust your Deployment Target to 8.0.
Hope this works for you

Answer (score 2):

I just figure it out , just use older version in your pod file created by unity to be like this

target 'Unity-iPhone' do
pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '3.17.0'
pod 'Firebase/Auth', '3.17.0'
pod 'Firebase/Core', '3.17.0'
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '7.13'
end

///note:
//

Don't forgot to set the Enable Modules (c and Objective-c) to yes in building setting for (Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK)

then
open folder from terminal and run:
->pod install
to update pods

:)

Comment: Don't forgot to set  the Enable Modules (c and Objective-c) to yes in building setting for (Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK)

Comment: this seemed to do the trick. must be an issue with the latest firebase sdk

Answer (score 1):

**Building Unity app with Firebase framework locally with Xcode:**

It is all about the iOS SDK version. This answer have part of the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41908040/8063631

Working on Mac environment.

When build in Unity to iOS. Be sure checked before: 
Assets -> iOS Resolver -> Setting

- Cocoapods Integration

  - Xcode Workspace - Add cocoa pods to the Xcode Workspace
- Auto install Cocoapods Tools in Editor

Build to iOS and open .workspace file.

Then go to Pods -> Podfile and add the past release version (3.7.0), because the 4.0.0 launch that error.

```
target 'Unity-iPhone' do
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
end
```

by (for example...)

```
target 'Unity-iPhone' do
    pod 'Firebase/Auth', '3.7.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Core', '3.7.0'
end
```

Close xCode IDE to avoid conflicts, then install Cocoapods if you don't have it yet (https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html):

Check with:

```
pod --version
```

Install with:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Go to your project folder by running Terminal and type:

```
pod install
```

It will remove the current versión and it replace it by the 3.7.0

Open xCode and press Product -> Clean and Product -> Build

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, after spend couple of hours i got the main problem.

It was the podfile library's defined specific version.

```
target 'Unity-iPhone' do
    pod 'Firebase/Auth', '4.10.0'
    pod 'Firebase/Core', '4.10.0'
end
```

When unity build iOS project's podfile they define their latest library version. But when from xcode/terminal try to update pod library from GIT and the specific version is not available then its failed to update and showing this error.

**Solution is simple just don't need to define the specific version. pod will update the GIT's latest version.**

```
target 'Unity-iPhone' do
    pod 'Firebase/Auth'
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved it for me. Just had to remove the specific versions and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

**CocoaPods**

CocoaPods is a dependency manager for iOS/macOS projects. It is used for installing external frameworks/libraries to your project.

---

**Building Unity app with Firebase framework locally with Xcode**:

You need to have cocoapods installed on your system: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#toc_3

---

**Building Unity app with Firebase framework on Unity Build Cloud:**

For the users who experience this issue on Unity Build Cloud server.

According to this forum thread: https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/build-failed-cocoapods.421286/ supporting cocoapods is not supported. (and probably not even scheduled for development).

Cocoapods are responsible for having all referenced libraries for your iOS project setup in your Xcode project. As they are not supported on Unity Build Cloud, you need to do it manually.

- make sure you have installed cocoapods on your macOS system: https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html#toc_3
- build your Unity app locally (don't trigger the build on the cloud). The build exports an Xcode project (which should be runnable). This Xcode project contains libraries (Frameworks) you need to add to the Unity project.

  - move all the *.framework folders from *EXPORTED_XCODE_PROJECT/Frameworks* to *YOUR_UNITY_PROJECT/Assets/Plugins/iOS* 
    e.g.: *FirebaseAnalytics.framework*, *FirebaseCore.framework*
  - Firebase requires iOS sqlite framework to be also included in the project. For that use this solution: 
    https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/problem-building-ios-app-with-cloud-build-using-google-analytics.390803/#post-2549911
    In the class *PostBuildProcessor* modify the method *ProcessPostBuild*,

    `// ObjC - needed for Firebase
    proj.AddBuildProperty (target, "OTHER_LDFLAGS", "-ObjC");`

    `List<string> frameworks = new List<string>() {
        "AdSupport.framework",
        "CoreData.framework",
        "SystemConfiguration.framework",
        "libz.dylib",
        "libsqlite3.dylib",
        "libApp.a",
        "libAnalytics.a"
    };`

Save the Unity project and by now the iOS Unity Build Cloud should work

Answer (score 0):

i had this issue and was fixed by updating the pods installation one way was clearing the locally cached copy and reinstall it again 
and another way was to force the installation to be from an online source

it worth mention that the building to IOS was succeeded

> Build completed with a result of 'Succeeded'

but had an error installing the pods

## Solution one

on the mac terminal change directory to the builded folder that should contain a `Podfile`

executed the following

```
$ pod repo remove master
$ pod install --repo-update
```

Rebuild the project from unity should install the `pods` automatically

## Other solution

#### Installing from GitHub

see [Firebase pods](https://cocoapods.org/pods/FirebaseDatabase) for more information

For releases starting with 5.0.0, the source for each release is also deployed to CocoaPods master and available via standard CocoaPods Podfile syntax.

These instructions can be used to access the Firebase repo at other branches, tags, or commits.

#### Background

See the Podfile Syntax Reference for instructions and options about overriding pod source locations.

Step-by-step Source Pod Installation Instructions

For iOS, copy a subset of the following lines to your `Podfile`:

`` pod 'Firebase' # To enable Firebase module, with `@import Firebase` support
pod 'FirebaseCore', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git', :tag => '5.0.0'
pod 'FirebaseAuth', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git', :tag => '5.0.0'
pod 'FirebaseDatabase', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git', :tag => '5.0.0'
pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git', :tag => '5.0.0'
pod 'FirebaseFunctions', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git', :tag => '5.0.0'
pod 'FirebaseMessaging', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git', :tag => '5.0.0'
pod 'FirebaseStorage', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git', :tag => '5.0.0' ``

For macOS and tvOS, copy a subset of the following:

`pod 'FirebaseCore', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git', :tag => '5.0.0'
pod 'FirebaseAuth', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git', :tag => '5.0.0'
pod 'FirebaseDatabase', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git', :tag => '5.0.0'
pod 'FirebaseStorage', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git', :tag => '5.0.0'`

1- Make sure you have at least CocoaPods version 1.4.0 - pod --version.

2- Delete pods for any components you don't need, except FirebaseCore must always be included.

3- Update the tags to the latest Firebase release. See the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios)

4- Run pod update.