# Unity3d Firebase Linker error - "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIREmailPasswordAuthProvider"

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine, linker

I have an issue running a unity3d project that uses Auth, RemoteConfig, and Database features from Firebase.

It worked well on my previous mac, but since the mac update it does not work anymore.

I do have cocoapods installed:

```
192-168-0-103:~ Alex$ pod --version
1.2.1
```

And I have the following linker flags:

```
$(inherited)
-weak_framework
CoreMotion
-weak-lSystem
-lxml2
-ObjC
-l"sqlite3"
-l"z"
```

The linker error I get is the following:

```
Showing Recent Issues
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIREmailPasswordAuthProvider", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in libAuth.a(credential_ios_ef8c3cf45c3329a5e5902f99026c639a.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The following solution  does not work for me:

[Firebase Xcode linker command error using Firebase Unity SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41896479/firebase-xcode-linker-command-error-using-firebase-unity-sdk)

And even if it worked, I very much prefer using Xcode project instead of workspace.

Anyone else ran into this with more success than I have?

Comment: did you try the solution from here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/dOdYeZdt0EI

Comment: did you ever resolve this issue

Comment: I didn't. I just rolled back to firebase 3.0.1 And I did try your solution, lysergic-acid, but it did not do the trick for me.