# Linker command Error when build Unity iOS project Locally

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, unity-game-engine

I did an super easy test of Firebase authentication, and I found this error that makes me impossible to build the application in iOS (xCode). I understand that people that will read this have some knowledges of this process, I will not deep in the explanation).

xCode: 8.3.2

Unity: 5.6.1

Cocoa Pod: 1.2.1

> Install Unity
>
> Create a new Project.
>
> Add Firebase SDK package to the project.
>
> Add a CreateUserByEmailAndPassword (same as example in firebase.google.com): https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth?hl=es-419
>
> Add that Component code to an GameObject.
>
> Build project.
>
> Open workspace in xCode.
>
> Fix signing issues.
>
> Build Project.

The Error here is:

```
ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: ltmp0 from /Users/brankofuenzalidalorca/Documents/Builds/iOS-1.6/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o)
ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: _unwind_tester from /Users/brankofuenzalidalorca/Documents/Builds/iOS-1.6/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIREmailPasswordAuthProvider", referenced from:
objc-class-ref in libAuth.a(credential_ios_ef8c3cf45c3329a5e5902f99026c639a.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It is not necessary to say that the code it is working correctly in Unity IDE. Another thing that I checked, when I did this test, was build the project in Unity to xCode and then build again but in xCode project.

Until I included the code, the project could build correcly in xCode. But, when I typed the code It stopped working.

¿Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase Xcode linker command error using Firebase Unity SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41896479/firebase-xcode-linker-command-error-using-firebase-unity-sdk)

Comment: It seems focused in Unity Build Cloud, and not Locally. My problem it is focused only Locally. I saw it but I can not fix it with his tools because is not Cloud.

Comment: @BrankodeEnero What is your iOS target version?

Comment: @mayo I'm sorry, but this issue is solved in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44244851/8063631. How can I close this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Cool. Don't worry, I will mark this question as duplicated ;)