# iOS Unity Cloud Build + Firebase database

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, ios-frameworks, unity3d-cloud-build

I was having an issue on Firebase Auth with iOS Unity Cloud Build before, so I try to manually add other required frameworks and libraries, then it can fix my issue. (following this thread: [Firebase Xcode linker command error using Firebase Unity SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41896479/firebase-xcode-linker-command-error-using-firebase-unity-sdk))

But when I start to integrate Firebase Database to my project, I always get this error on iOS Unity Cloud Build

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_utf8_nextCharSafeBody", referenced from:
-[FSRWebSocket _innerPumpScanner] in FirebaseDatabase(FSRWebSocket.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It already took me two days, but I still can't fix it yet..
Does anyone know how to fix this??

Comment: See the [description in the thread you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41896479/firebase-xcode-linker-command-error-using-firebase-unity-sdk) about adding `libicucore.tbd`.

Comment: Problem is I already added that TT