# Unity-iOS Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I got a stuck when I built Unity projects from Unity version 5.6.4f1, Xcode version 10.0.1, API compatibility level .NET 2.0. 
I've been trying most of the ways I searched from google but none of them solve my problem. Please give me a suggestion to overcome this obsession :( 
[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZGkD.png)
Here is the log.

```html
Ld /Users/danhdat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dtlheqveczyzyvfvxmrmcrzqvreg/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/magicalanimal.app/magicalanimal normal arm64 (in target: Unity-iPhone)
    cd /Users/danhdat/Desktop/Projects/MagicBook\ 4D/BuildIOS
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=11.0
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.1.sdk -L/Users/danhdat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dtlheqveczyzyvfvxmrmcrzqvreg/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos -L/Users/danhdat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dtlheqveczyzyvfvxmrmcrzqvreg/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/FirebaseAuth -L/Users/danhdat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dtlheqveczyzyvfvxmrmcrzqvreg/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/FirebaseCore -L/Users/danhdat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dtlheqveczyzyvfvxmrmcrzqvreg/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/FirebaseMessaging -L/Users/danhdat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dtlheqveczyzyvfvxmrmcrzqvreg/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/FirebaseStorage -L/Users/danhdat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dtlheqveczyzyvfvxmrmcrzqvreg/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher -L/Users/danhdat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dtlheqveczyzyvfvxmrmcrzqvreg/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac -L/Users/danhdat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dtlheqveczyzyvfvxmrmcrzqvreg/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Protobuf -L/Users/danhdat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dtlheqveczyzyvfvxmrmcrzqvreg/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/nanopb -L/Users/danhdat/Desktop/Projects/MagicBook\ 4D/BuildIOS -L/Users/danhdat/Desktop/Projects/MagicBook\ 4D/BuildIOS/Libraries -L/Users/danhdat/Desktop/Projects/MagicBook\ 4D/BuildIOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS -L/Users/danhdat/Desktop/Projects/MagicBook\ 4D/BuildIOS/Libraries/Plugins/iOS/Firebase -F/Users/danhdat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dtlheqveczyzyvfvxmrmcrzqvreg/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos -F/Users/danhdat/Desktop/Projects/MagicBook\ 4D/BuildIOS/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/danhdat/Desktop/Projects/MagicBook\ 4D/BuildIOS/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks -F/Users/danhdat/Desktop/Projects/MagicBook\ 4D/BuildIOS/Frameworks/Plugins/iOS -filelist /Users/danhdat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dtlheqveczyzyvfvxmrmcrzqvreg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/magicalanimal.LinkFileList -Xlinker -map -Xlinker /Users/danhdat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dtlheqveczyzyvfvxmrmcrzqvreg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/magicalanimal-LinkMap-normal-arm64.txt -miphoneos-version-min=11.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/danhdat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dtlheqveczyzyvfvxmrmcrzqvreg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.
build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/magicalanimal_lto.o -stdlib=libc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -lc++ -ObjC -lFirebaseAuth -lFirebaseCore -lFirebaseMessaging -lFirebaseStorage -lGTMSessionFetcher -lGoogleToolboxForMac -lProtobuf -lc++ -lnanopb -lsqlite3 -lz -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework FirebaseNanoPB -framework Foundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -weak_framework CoreMotion -weak-lSystem -framework AssetsLibrary -framework Security -framework MediaToolbox -liPhone-lib -framework CoreText -framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework AVFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreMedia -weak_framework CoreMotion -framework CoreVideo -framework Foundation -framework MediaPlayer -framework OpenAL -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -liconv.2 -lVuforiaUnityPlayer -lFirebaseCppAuth -lVuforia -lCaptureAndSave -framework GoogleSignIn -lFirebaseCppMessaging -lFirebaseCppAnalytics -framework gpg -lFirebaseCppApp -framework GoogleSignInDependencies -lFirebaseCppStorage -framework StoreKit -weak_framework Metal -lPods-Unity-iPhone -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/danhdat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dtlheqveczyzyvfvxmrmcrzqvreg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Unity-iPhone.build/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/Unity-iPhone.build/Objects-normal/arm64/magicalanimal_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/danhdat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-dtlheqveczyzyvfvxmrmcrzqvreg/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/magicalanimal.app/magicalanimal

ld: warning: arm64 function not 4-byte aligned: _unwind_tester from /Users/danhdat/Desktop/Projects/MagicBook 4D/BuildIOS/Libraries/libiPhone-lib.a(unwind_test_arm64.o)
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_GTLObject.childCache_", referenced from:
      -[GTLObject(GPGAdditions) encodeWithCoder:] in gpg(GTLObject+GPGAdditions.o)
      -[GTLObject(GPGAdditions) initWithCoder:] in gpg(GTLObject+GPGAdditions.o)
  "_CTRadioAccessTechnologyGPRS", referenced from:
      l5039 in gpg(libgpg.a-arm64-master.o)
  "_CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMA1x", referenced from:
      l5039 in gpg(libgpg.a-arm64-master.o)
  "_CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSDPA", referenced from:
      l5039 in gpg(libgpg.a-arm64-master.o)
  "_CTRadioAccessTechnologyHSUPA", referenced from:
      l5039 in gpg(libgpg.a-arm64-master.o)
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_GTLObject.userProperties_", referenced from:
      -[GTLObject(GPGAdditions) encodeWithCoder:] in gpg(GTLObject+GPGAdditions.o)
      -[GTLObject(GPGAdditions) initWithCoder:] in gpg(GTLObject+GPGAdditions.o)
  "_CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevB", referenced from:
      l5039 in gpg(libgpg.a-arm64-master.o)
  "_CTRadioAccessTechnologyLTE", referenced from:
l5039 in gpg(libgpg.a-arm64-master.o)
  "_videoPlayerGetStatusIOS", referenced from:
      _VideoPlaybackBehaviour_OnRenderObject_m2540042216 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_GetStatus_m3147268202 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _U3CPrepareVideoU3Ec__Iterator2_MoveNext_m4003923966 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlaybackController_HandleTap_m2760031326 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerGetStatus_m1475928605 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerGetStatusIOS_m1855316680 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
     (maybe you meant: _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerGetStatusIOS_m1855316680)
  "_videoPlayerInitIOS", referenced from:
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerInit_m4104006758 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerInitIOS_m3962364758 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
     (maybe you meant: _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerInitIOS_m3962364758)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLService", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLServiceGames in gpg(GTLServiceGames.o)
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLServiceGames)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLServiceTicket", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GPGServiceTicket in gpg(GPGService.o)
  "_kGTMOAuth2ErrorInvalidRequest", referenced from:
      ___49-[GPGService executeOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke in gpg(GPGService.o)
  "_CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORevA", referenced from:
      l5039 in gpg(libgpg.a-arm64-master.o)
  "_kGTMOAuth2ErrorInvalidGrant", referenced from:
      ___49-[GPGService executeOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke in gpg(GPGService.o)
  "_videoPlayerPlayIOS", referenced from:
      _U3CPrepareVideoU3Ec__Iterator2_MoveNext_m4003923966 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_Play_m1992276925 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlaybackController_HandleTap_m2760031326 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerPlay_m1892101403 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerPlayIOS_m4173957476 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
     (maybe you meant: _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerPlayIOS_m4173957476)
  "_videoPlayerGetVideoWidthIOS", referenced from:
      _VideoPlaybackBehaviour_InitVideoTexture_m829181239 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_GetVideoWidth_m1642609846 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _U3CPrepareVideoU3Ec__Iterator2_MoveNext_m4003923966 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerGetVideoWidth_m1870841896 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerGetVideoWidthIOS_m3040234369 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
     (maybe you meant: _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerGetVideoWidthIOS_m3040234369)
  "_kGTMOAuth2ErrorInvalidScope", referenced from:
      ___49-[GPGService executeOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke in gpg(GPGService.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLQueryPlus", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in gpg(GPGPlayerPickerViewControllerDelegateMock.o)
objc-class-ref in gpg(GPGPlayerServiceMock.o)
      objc-class-ref in gpg(libgpg.a-arm64-master.o)
  "_CTRadioAccessTechnologyeHRPD", referenced from:
      l5039 in gpg(libgpg.a-arm64-master.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMOAuth2Authentication", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in gpg(GPGManager.o)
      objc-class-ref in gpg(libgpg.a-arm64-master.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMSessionFetcher", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in gpg(GPGClearcutLogger.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTMOAuth2SignIn", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in gpg(GPGManager.o)
      objc-class-ref in gpg(libgpg.a-arm64-master.o)
  "_videoPlayerGetVideoHeightIOS", referenced from:
      _VideoPlaybackBehaviour_InitVideoTexture_m829181239 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_GetVideoHeight_m1301576521 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _U3CPrepareVideoU3Ec__Iterator2_MoveNext_m4003923966 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerGetVideoHeight_m1488125603 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerGetVideoHeightIOS_m231081034 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
     (maybe you meant: _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerGetVideoHeightIOS_m231081034)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLServicePlus", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in gpg(GPGPlayerPickerViewControllerDelegateMock.o)
      objc-class-ref in gpg(GPGPlayerServiceMock.o)
      objc-class-ref in gpg(libgpg.a-arm64-master.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLCollectionObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLGamesEventDefinitionListResponse in gpg(GTLGamesEventDefinitionListResponse.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLGamesLeaderboardListResponse in gpg(GTLGamesLeaderboardListResponse.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLGamesPlayerAchievementListResponse in gpg(GTLGamesPlayerAchievementListResponse.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLGamesPlayerEventListResponse in gpg(GTLGamesPlayerEventListResponse.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLGamesPlayerLeaderboardScoreListResponse in gpg(GTLGamesPlayerLeaderboardScoreListResponse.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLGamesRoomList in gpg(GTLGamesRoomList.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLGamesTurnBasedMatchList in gpg(GTLGamesTurnBasedMatchList.o)
      ...
  "_videoPlayerGetLengthIOS", referenced from:
      _VideoPlayerHelper_GetLength_m4032419859 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerGetLength_m1774387097 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerGetLengthIOS_m2958159138 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
     (maybe you meant: _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerGetLengthIOS_m2958159138)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLService", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLServiceGames in gpg(GTLServiceGames.o)
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLServiceGames)
  "_kGTMOAuth2ErrorUnauthorizedClient", referenced from:
      ___49-[GPGService executeOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke in gpg(GPGService.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OpenInChromeController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in gpg(GPGSettingsViewController.o)
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLQuery", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLQueryGamesManagement in gpg(GTLQueryGamesManagement.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLQueryGames in gpg(GTLQueryGames.o)
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLQueryGames, _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLQueryGamesManagement )
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLQuery", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLQueryGamesManagement in gpg(GTLQueryGamesManagement.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLQueryGames in gpg(GTLQueryGames.o)
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLQueryGames, _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLQueryGamesManagement )
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_LAContext", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleSignIn(MDMPasscodeCache_2f4eca94c01a9a3abfb317858c26b472.o)
  "_videoPlayerGetCurrentBufferingPercentageIOS", referenced from:
      _VideoPlayerHelper_GetCurrentBufferingPercentage_m3764199406 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerGetCurrentBufferingPercentage_m3662509572 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerGetCurrentBufferingPercentageIOS_m1151287047 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
     (maybe you meant: _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerGetCurrentBufferingPercentageIOS_m1151287047)
  "_videoPlayerLoadIOS", referenced from:
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerLoad_m235514828 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerLoadIOS_m3211674785 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
     (maybe you meant: _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerLoadIOS_m3211674785)
  "_videoPlayerStopIOS", referenced from:
      _VideoPlayerHelper_Stop_m2503777039 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerStop_m2479749713 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerStopIOS_m1945539750 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
     (maybe you meant: _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerStopIOS_m1945539750)
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_GTLObject.surrogates_", referenced from:
      -[GTLObject(GPGAdditions) encodeWithCoder:] in gpg(GTLObject+GPGAdditions.o)
      -[GTLObject(GPGAdditions) initWithCoder:] in gpg(GTLObject+GPGAdditions.o)
  "_kGTMOAuth2ErrorInvalidClient", referenced from:
      ___49-[GPGService executeOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke in gpg(GPGService.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLCollectionObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesEventDefinitionListResponse in gpg(GTLGamesEventDefinitionListResponse.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesLeaderboardListResponse in gpg(GTLGamesLeaderboardListResponse.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesPlayerAchievementListResponse in gpg(GTLGamesPlayerAchievementListResponse.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesPlayerEventListResponse in gpg(GTLGamesPlayerEventListResponse.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesPlayerLeaderboardScoreListResponse in gpg(GTLGamesPlayerLeaderboardScoreListResponse.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesRoomList in gpg(GTLGamesRoomList.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesTurnBasedMatchList in gpg(GTLGamesTurnBasedMatchList.o)
      ...
  "_videoPlayerIsPlayableFullscreenIOS", referenced from:
_VideoPlaybackMenuOptions_ToggleFullscreenMode_m726997124 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_IsPlayableFullscreen_m3667057644 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerIsPlayableFullscreen_m4253182806 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerIsPlayableFullscreenIOS_m1755006933 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
     (maybe you meant: _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerIsPlayableFullscreenIOS_m1755006933)
  "_videoPlayerUnloadIOS", referenced from:
      _VideoPlayerHelper_Unload_m1616588048 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerUnload_m2085537158 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerUnloadIOS_m364788659 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
     (maybe you meant: _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerUnloadIOS_m364788659)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLServiceTicket", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GPGServiceTicket in gpg(GPGService.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesManagementHiddenPlayer in gpg(GTLGamesManagementHiddenPlayer.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesManagementPlayer in gpg(GTLGamesManagementPlayer.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesAchievementDefinition in gpg(GTLGamesAchievementDefinition.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesAchievementIncrementResponse in gpg(GTLGamesAchievementIncrementResponse.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesAchievementSetStepsAtLeastResponse in gpg(GTLGamesAchievementSetStepsAtLeastResponse.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesAchievementUpdateResponse in gpg(GTLGamesAchievementUpdateResponse.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLGamesEventBatchRecordFailure in gpg(GTLGamesEventBatchRecordFailure.o)
      ...
  "_CTRadioAccessTechnologyCDMAEVDORev0", referenced from:
      l5039 in gpg(libgpg.a-arm64-master.o)
  "_videoPlayerSeekToIOS", referenced from:
      _U3CPrepareVideoU3Ec__Iterator2_MoveNext_m4003923966 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_SeekTo_m2766766085 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlaybackMenuOptions_ToggleFullscreenMode_m726997124 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerSeekTo_m2108514915 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerSeekToIOS_m2239692620 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
     (maybe you meant: _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerSeekToIOS_m2239692620)
  "_CTRadioAccessTechnologyWCDMA", referenced from:
      l5039 in gpg(libgpg.a-arm64-master.o)
  "_ImgToAlbum", referenced from:
      _RenderTextureCamera_ImgToAlbum_m1395751564 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_12.o
      _RenderTextureCamera_saveImgToGallery_m745645765 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_12.o
     (maybe you meant: _RenderTextureCamera_ImgToAlbum_m1395751564)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CTTelephonyNetworkInfo", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in gpg(libgpg.a-arm64-master.o)
  "_videoPlayerSetVideoTexturePtrIOS", referenced from:
      _U3CPrepareVideoU3Ec__Iterator2_MoveNext_m4003923966 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
_VideoPlayerHelper_SetVideoTexturePtr_m1144094767 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerSetVideoTexturePtr_m3252772981 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerSetVideoTexturePtrIOS_m2476490678 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
     (maybe you meant: _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerSetVideoTexturePtrIOS_m2476490678)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GSDK_GTMSessionFetcherService", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in gpg(GIPNetworkImage.o)
  "_kGTMOAuth2ErrorUnsupportedGrantType", referenced from:
      ___49-[GPGService executeOperation:completionHandler:]_block_invoke in gpg(GPGService.o)
  "_CTRadioAccessTechnologyEdge", referenced from:
      l5039 in gpg(libgpg.a-arm64-master.o)
  "_videoPlayerGetCurrentPositionIOS", referenced from:
      _VideoPlaybackBehaviour_OnApplicationPause_m2056660370 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_GetCurrentPosition_m4118493247 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlaybackController_HandleTap_m2760031326 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerGetCurrentPosition_m3242347473 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerGetCurrentPositionIOS_m2470028788 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
     (maybe you meant: _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerGetCurrentPositionIOS_m2470028788)
  "_videoPlayerIsPlayableOnTextureIOS", referenced from:
      _U3CPrepareVideoU3Ec__Iterator2_MoveNext_m4003923966 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_IsPlayableOnTexture_m1678376193 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlaybackController_HandleTap_m2760031326 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlaybackTapHandler_OnDoubleTap_m2013819141 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerIsPlayableOnTexture_m1091384519 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerIsPlayableOnTextureIOS_m313003860 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
     (maybe you meant: _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerIsPlayableOnTextureIOS_m313003860)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLGamesManagementHiddenPlayer in gpg(GTLGamesManagementHiddenPlayer.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLGamesManagementPlayer in gpg(GTLGamesManagementPlayer.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLGamesAchievementDefinition in gpg(GTLGamesAchievementDefinition.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLGamesAchievementIncrementResponse in gpg(GTLGamesAchievementIncrementResponse.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLGamesAchievementSetStepsAtLeastResponse in gpg(GTLGamesAchievementSetStepsAtLeastResponse.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLGamesAchievementUpdateResponse in gpg(GTLGamesAchievementUpdateResponse.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GTLGamesEventBatchRecordFailure in gpg(GTLGamesEventBatchRecordFailure.o)
      ...
  "_videoPlayerSetVolumeIOS", referenced from:
      _VideoPlayerHelper_SetVolume_m2990968142 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerSetVolume_m2321198500 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
_VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerSetVolumeIOS_m3678970657 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
     (maybe you meant: _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerSetVolumeIOS_m3678970657)
  "_OBJC_IVAR_$_GTLObject.json_", referenced from:
      -[GTLObject(GPGAdditions) encodeWithCoder:] in gpg(GTLObject+GPGAdditions.o)
      -[GTLObject(GPGAdditions) initWithCoder:] in gpg(GTLObject+GPGAdditions.o)
  "_videoPlayerPauseIOS", referenced from:
      _VideoPlaybackController_HandleTap_m2760031326 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlaybackController_PauseOtherVideos_m1432676778 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_Pause_m2396057477 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlaybackMenuOptions_ToggleFullscreenMode_m726997124 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlaybackTapHandler_OnDoubleTap_m2013819141 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerPause_m4191091815 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerPauseIOS_m3696506696 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      ...
     (maybe you meant: _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerPauseIOS_m3696506696)
  "_videoPlayerOnPauseIOS", referenced from:
      _VideoPlaybackBehaviour_OnApplicationPause_m2056660370 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_OnPause_m3355667376 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerOnPause_m615032094 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerOnPauseIOS_m1381523325 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
     (maybe you meant: _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerOnPauseIOS_m1381523325)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GTLPlusPerson", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in gpg(GPGPlayerServiceMock.o)
  "_videoPlayerDeinitIOS", referenced from:
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerDeinit_m2996476724 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerDeinitIOS_m3635511669 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
     (maybe you meant: _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerDeinitIOS_m3635511669)
  "_videoPlayerUpdateVideoDataIOS", referenced from:
      _VideoPlaybackBehaviour_OnRenderObject_m2540042216 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_UpdateVideoData_m368678036 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerUpdateVideoData_m1122450783 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
      _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerUpdateVideoDataIOS_m3521022778 in Bulk_Assembly-CSharp_19.o
     (maybe you meant: _VideoPlayerHelper_videoPlayerUpdateVideoDataIOS_m3521022778)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41896479/firebase-xcode-linker-command-error-using-firebase-unity-sdk)

Comment: @ArnabHore I've try that but it's not solve my problem